# How to Pass results from Google Forms to Google Data Studio using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms, looker-studio

I've been working on Google Apps Script for the past few days, a friend of mine created a template of PDF in Google Data Studio. We also have a Google Sheet that came from the Google Forms result. Here are the questions I want to resolve.

1. When the user submits the form, I want the record of that submitted form to populate the Google Data Studio PDF and export it as PDF using Google Apps Script
   *(just that single record to create a PDF every time the user submits.)*
2. I want to use Google Apps Script to get every record in the existing Google Sheet to populate the Google Data Studio PDF Template and export it as PDF.

Comment: What do you mean a Data Studio PDF? Data Studio is a reporting tool. In fact, I don't think Data Studio has an API right now so you can't programatically do anything with it. What you can do is take the form submission, or the data from the Google Sheet, and put it into a Google Docs template file that you then save as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use Apps Script to interact with the Data Studio interface in any way. It is currently not possible.
2. Again, you cannot use Apps Script to initiate the PDF export. However, if all your data is in a Google Sheet, you can just build a dashboard off that in Data Studio and manually export the PDF. As your data gets updated, dashboard will also get updated. You can initiate the PDF export manually whenever you want.